# How to analyze the space usage within pdf document?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, ocr

I have this 7mb pdf that I made from 65 scanned B/W images. After OCR, the document becomes 32mb.

I have never seen text taking up so much space. (in theory 25mb should give me 25 million letters uncompressed) Saving in plain text I have about 4KB/page * 65 = +/- 280KB of text.

Leaves the rest of 32mb for the positioning since I make a searchable image? Unlikely.

Something seems wrong and I want to have a look at the space taken up by different parts of the pdf, but I can't find any tool that seems to do this.

EDIT:
The issue with the pdf in question has been resolved. The culprit was having *searchable image* vs *searchable image (exact)*. It must have resampled some of the images which made them a lot bigger. Still interested in an answer to the question though.

Comment: online tool to analyze the size of PDF files up to 200MB: [WeCompress PDF file analyzer](https://www.wecompress.com/en/analyze) ([via](https://neuxpower.com/blog/why-is-pdf-file-so-big-and-how-to-reduce-pdf-file-size))

Answer (score 4):

The tool you are looking for is the Audit Space Usage tool in Adobe Acrobat. This tool will give you a byte by byte breakdown of which components of your PDF are contributing to the file size.

Here's a [video demonstrating how to find the Audit Space Usage tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75UxcNeYoUk). For some reason Adobe has hidden it in Acrobat.

The feature can be found under **File > Save as... > Optimized > Audit space usage**.

Comment: That is part of the way, unfortunately it will only say something like images 98%, which doesn't yet help you identify which images are consuming most in order to reduce them better.

Comment: to "identify which images are consuming most" you can use `pdfimages -all input.pdf images` and `du -b images-* | sort -n`